# Ffmpeg to duplicate an audio stream and encode this new stream

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mapping

I have some video files that I need to re-encode due to compatibility issues. They are currently mkv files with h.264 video and ac3-a52 audio. I want to keep the h.264 video, convert the container to m4v and create two audio tracks, one with the original ac3-a52 and one copied from that but in aac stereo.

I assume there has to be some sort of audio stream mapping command but I don't know how to map and re-encode at the same time. What command should I enter into ffmpeg to achieve this?

Also, what is the difference between ac3 and ac3-a52? Will an apple TV still be able to pass through ac3-a52 or does that have to be converted to ac3?

Answer (score 28):

this works for me:

```
ffmpeg -y -i Source.mkv -map 0:v -c:v copy -map 0:a -c:a copy -map 0:a -strict -2 -c:a aac out.mkv
```

- `-y` – A global option to overwrite the output file if it already exists.
- `-map 0:v` – Designate the video stream(s) from the first input as a source for the output file.
- `-c:v copy` – [Stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the video. This just muxes the input to the output. No re-encoding occurs.
- `-map 0:a` – Designate the audio stream(s) from the first input as a source for the output file.
- `-c:a copy` – [Stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the audio. This just muxes the input to the output. No re-encoding occurs.
- `-strict -2 -c:a aac` – Use the native FFmpeg AAC audio encoder. `-strict -2` is required as a way that you acknowledge that the encoder is designated as experimental. It is not a great encoder, but it is not too bad at higher bitrates.

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolby_AC-3#Dolby_Digital), there is no difference between AC3 and ATSC A/52: the 1st one is the name of the codec, the 2nd is the name of the standard specifying the AC3 codec. Maybe someone have more knowledge about it?

Comment: What does the -strict option do?

Comment: It allows you to use the built-in AAC encoder which is still considered "Experimental". `-strict -2` is the same as `-strict experimental`

Comment: I found I needed to use -c:a:0  and -c:a:1  for the output streams or they both ended up as aac

Comment: What part of the command duplicates the audio I’m not seeing it

Comment: -c:a twice basically means the first time is ignored. So both audio streams are going to be encode the same, removing the original and duplicating the encoded output.

Comment: Is the AAC encoder still experimental? Should this answer be edited if it is no longer the case?

Comment: Why the second `-map 0:a`?

Answer (score 8):

I'm doing the same as the OP, but with an m4v container.  I'm using the MacPorts "nonfree" variant of ffmpeg so that I can use libfaac, which gives better audio quality than the built-in AAC encoder and also had the same issue as @dkam.  The command line I ended using is like this:

`ffmpeg -i input.m4v -map 0:v -c:v copy -map 0:a -c:a:0 copy -map 0:a -c:a:1 libfaac output.m4v`

(The videos are for playback on an iPad, which doesn't seem to be able to handle ac3.)

Answer (score 1):

This command will take a video with 1 audio stream, and downmix to stereo and convert the audio stream and add it as a 2nd audio stream. It will be in **AAC 384k**.

`ffmpeg -i INPUT.mkv -strict -2 -map 0 -c copy -map 0:a:0 -c:a:1 aac -b:a 384k -ac 2 OUTPUT.mkv`

## Explanation of the command

- `ffmpeg -i INPUT.mkv` The application and input file
- `-strict -2` Enable downmixing support
- `-map 0` Tell ffmpeg read all Video, Audio, and Subtitle streams for the following arguments

  - `-c copy` Copy everything
- `-map 0:a:0` Tell ffmpeg to read the first audio stream for the following arguments

  - `-c:a:1 aac` Output the audio to a 2nd audio channel (0 = first channel) in aac format. **Important!** You must change the output channel to a higher number if there are multiple audio streams to prevent overwriting them.
  - `-b:a 384k` 384k bitrate (I don't know what's good for aac stereo but this is really high since it's for 5.1 aac)
  - `-ac 2` Downmix to stereo
- `OUTPUT.mkv` Output file

## More examples

A video with two audio streams. Creating a third audio stream by encoding the first.

`ffmpeg -i INPUT.mkv -strict -2 -map 0 -c copy -map 0:a:0 -c:a:2 aac -b:a 384k -ac 2 OUTPUT.mkv`

Again a video with two audio streams, but you want to encode the second one

`ffmpeg -i INPUT.mkv -strict -2 -map 0 -c copy -map 0:a:1 -c:a:2 aac -b:a 384k -ac 2 OUTPUT.mkv`

Comment: `-strict -2` should not be needed with modern versions it seems.